# Is there a way for a subclass to inherit from different parents based on input in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, inheritance, subclass

I have a parent class that's an abstract base class called "curve". It contains x and y values of some discrete curve, and a few other attributes and abstract methods. Then I have subclasses that populate these attributes for different types of curves, like "circle" and "line". Now I want to make another class called "function" that is a subclass of a specific type of curve, and contains the values of the function on that curve and methods for computing those values.

Is there a way to dynamically inherit from one of the curve subclasses based on an instantiating input, say `fct_circ = function("circle")` is a sublcass of circle, but `fct_line = function("line")` is a subclass of line? Does it even make sense to set up the classes in this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a factory method with a inner class, which returns an instance with a dynamic parent, like so:

```py
def function(curve):
        
   class CurveFunction(curve): 
      # implement

   return CurveFunction

circleFunction = function(Circle)
```

You could then also implement some kind of case match for different curves and return each `CurveFunction` accordingly.